# How to fix ES6 module syntax issue causing "Cannot Find Module" and "Cannot use import statement outside a module" errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, github-pages, es6-modules

## I can't see my page. Help!

I belive it's a problem related to ES6 module syntax, however i don't know how to solve it.

When I type *npm start* in the termninal I get this:

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\55319\Desktop\my-first-website\my-app\index.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

And on the console (on github) I get:
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module*

Here's my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './src/index.css';
import App from './src/App.js';
import reportWebVitals from './src/reportWebVitals.js';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();
```

[Here's my repository on Github](https://github.com/snoozleEmily/The-Coding-Journey-Of-Emily)

I have already added the type module in my html:
`<script type="module" src="../index.js"></script>`

I also installed babel but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Hi. Are you trying to work on this app locally, or deploy it to GH pages? I cloned it and took a look and to work on it locally I had to change a few things before it would work, so those may also have a bearing on the GH deployment... at a guess.

Comment: Are you using the files created from running `npm run build` ?

Comment: @Andy both actually!

Comment: @Keith I don't think so